# Angularjs $http.get returning JSON data as a string with escaped quotes instead of json

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Interesting problem here.  I have restful backend that returns JSON.  When I access the api through the browser it returns a validated json array with a json object.

> [{"GUID_Auth":null,"Email_Address":"abc@aol,"Measure_Id":1,"Title":"Prop
>   41"}]

but when I make a $http.get request through angularjs I instead get back a string with escaped quotes

> got success: "[{\"GUID_Auth\":null,\"Email_Address\":\"abc@aol\",\"Measure_Id\":1,\"Title\":\"Prop
>   41\"}]"

Here is a snippet of my angularjs controller code

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
  $scope.GetData = function(){
    var responsePromise = $http.get('http://backend.api');
    responsePromise.success(function(data,status,headers,config){
      console.log('got success: ' + data);
      console.log('test'+ data[0].Email_Address)
    });
    responsePromise.error(function(data,status,headers,config){
      alert('ajax failed');
    });
  },
```

This is very perplexing any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$http is serializing the data, so parse it before returning it
`JSON.parse(data)`